# show checkbox on all lines in jqm listview

Tags: listview, checkbox, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQM.

I have a JQM listview already rendered. I want to add a checkbox to all lines in the listview and show it on each line when I click on a global Delete button. However I have only been able to get the first li to render with a checkbox.

Any suggestions?